# How to write a `.bat` script to change folder security automatically?

Tags: windows-7, automation, batch-file, internet-security, public-folders

Currently I'm trying to deploy BugNET application on my machine following [their official document](http://bugnetproject.com/Documentation/tabid/57/topic/Installation/Default.aspx). One of those steps is to change the security property of the published folder proceeded as below screenshot - providing `Full control` for the selected `IIS` user on the folder.

I want to write an batch/.bat script that can automate this manual task when executed. Is it possible and if it is, please show me how. Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I use when installing a PHP application on IIS 7.5 and want to give the 'Everyone' use Full Control (F) to the 'Cache' folder. I also include Object Inherit (OI) and Container Inherit (CI).

> icacls cache\ /grant Everyone:(OI)(CI)(F)

Comment: @Evangelist Thank you! 

What does icacls stand for?